# \DeclareMathAlphabet does not work on beamer?

Tags: math-mode, sans-serif, helvetica

I am trying to use Helvetica for `\mathsf` in a beamer presentation. For that, I have

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
```

on my preamble. This is what I use in another LaTeX document of mine of the class `book` and I get the desired result. I don't know why it does not work on beamer. I have tried to change between encodings `T1` and `TS1` instead of `OT1` in the previous code and it does nothing. I have looked through TSE questions and I have found nothing related. How can I fix this?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you give a minimal example that demonstrates the bug?

Comment: If you’re setting individual alphabets, you might want `[professionalfonts]`. This turns off some redefinitions of the alphabets.